# Android spinner is showing with two triangle icons and the popup items are unselectable

Tags: android, material-design, android-spinner

I really don't know how to put this, but i am having a very weird output in my spinner which looks like this

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/airtime_subcriber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/subcribers"
    android:theme="@style/Spinner_style" />
```

The Spinner Style

```
<style name="Spinner_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined</item>
</style>
```

Output is like this

[image]

I have no idea where the extra triangle icon is coming from...

my question is: how do i remove the extra triangle and have a normal spinner that looks like the one on the left below:

[image]

Comment: just remove `android:theme="@style/Spinner_style"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to add theme attribute

```
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/airtime_subcriber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/subcribers" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting Spinner style to the elements, so you get spinner full of spinners (thats why the second triangle)
try

```
<style name="Spinner_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle</item>
```